# MailChimp API 3.0 Batch update - Always pending, total_operations:0

Tags: php, mailchimp

Trying to update a batch of emails. I think I've tried every way to do this, but my use of [DrewM's MailChimp wrapper](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api) only returns the following `$result` content:

```
Array ( [id] => 1234abcd [status] => pending [total_operations] => 0 [finished_operations] => 0
```

And so on. No errors, but no operations!

Essentially, my code looks like this, where `$emails` stores all the emails in an array.

```
include("MailChimp.php");
include("Batch.php");

$list_id = "1234abcd";

use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
use \DrewM\MailChimp\Batch;
$apiKey = 'aslkjf84983hg84938h89gd-us13';

if(!isset($emails)){ // If not sending bulk requests
    $MailChimp = new MailChimp($apiKey);
    $subscriber_hash = $MailChimp->subscriberHash($email);
    $result = $MailChimp->patch("lists/$list_id/members/$subscriber_hash",
        array(
            'status' => 'subscribed',
        )
    );

/* SENDING BATCH OF EMAILS */
} else if($emails){
    $MailChimp = new MailChimp($apiKey);
    $Batch     = $MailChimp->new_batch();
    $i = 1;
    foreach($emails as &$value){
        $Batch->post("op".$i, "lists/$list_id/members", [
            'email_address' => $value,
            'status'        => 'subscribed',
        ]);
        $i++;
    }
    $result = $Batch->execute(); // Send the request (not working I guess)
    $MailChimp->new_batch($batch_id); // Now get results
    $result = $Batch->check_status();
    print_r($result);
}
```

If anyone can see what I'm not seeing, I'll be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. After talking with a rep at MailChimp, he helped to find two major problems.

Instead of using a `POST` method, he said to use `PUT`, when working with already existing emails. POST is best used for adding emails, while PUT can add and update emails.

So, change

```
$Batch->post
```

to

```
$Batch->put
```

Secondly, after successfully sending requests and getting errors in the `$result`, he found they were 405 errors and told me to add the `md5` hash to my emails.

So, change

```
$Batch->post("op".$i, "lists/$list_id/members", [ ...
```

to

```
$subscriber_hash = $MailChimp->subscriberHash($value);
$Batch->put("op$i", "lists/$list_id/members/$subscriber_hash", [ ...
```

And they sent me a MailChimp stocking cap for being a good sport :-)

Veni. Vidi. Vici.